# Why is this JavaScript interpreted two different ways?

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain why this JavaScript is interpreted two different ways?

This:

```
var testnum = $("<div>00000001</div>").text();
var test = "claimid:" + + testnum;
alert(test);
```

This throws an alert that displays: claimid:1

Where this:

```
var testnum = $("<div>00000001</div>").text();
var test = "claimid:" + testnum;
alert(test);
```

This throws an alert that displays: claimid:00000001

I get the reason as to why the second treats testnum as a string, but why does it treat testnum as a number on the first.

Comment: Because you added an operator that converts to number. You'll find that when you use operators, they'll perform operations. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two plus signs. The second plus sign is the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29), which in Javascript has the sole purpose of converting it's operand to a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Answer (score 1):

> but why does it treat testnum as a number on the first.

Remember, in JavaScript, `+` can be used as a unary operator to convert a string to a number.  That's what you have here with the *second* plus sign:

```
var test = "claimid:" + + testnum;
//                      ^ HERE
```

In either case, the string concatenation takes higher precedence than numeric addition (where applicable), but the first case converts your value of `00000001` to a *number*, which is why a plain old `1` is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, + is interpreted as the unary positive operator. Consider `x = -5`. The - is the unary negative operator. + takes a value and returns its numeric value.